# Can nonlinear systems of 2 equations in 2 variables always be solved using the substitution method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

If I have a system of 2 nonlinear equations in 2 variables, can it always be solved using the substitution method?

Comment: Not always but there exists many cases where it can be solved by direct substitution. However it isn't recommended to use direct substitution that much.

Comment: Even with linear equations, there might not exist a solution.